# DelphiXE5で作成中のアプリに、コンソールアプリのようにアイコンリソースを持たせたくない

Tags: delphi

現在delphiXE5を使って、VCLフォームアプリにて細かなツール（モジュール）群を大量に作っているのですが、特に業務で使うアプリであり、いちいちアイコンを設定するのが面倒です。

コンソールアプリのように、アプリそのものがアイコンリソースを持たないようなEXEをを作りたいのですがどうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Delphiのインストール先のbinフォルダ内にdelphi_PROJECTICON.icoというファイルがあり、これを置き換えることでアプリケーションのデフォルトアイコンを変更することができるようです。このファイルを空の(0バイトということではなく)ものに置き換えるのはどうでしょう？
詳細はヘルプの[アプリケーション アイコンの作成と配置](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/ja/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3_%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%A8%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE#.E3.83.87.E3.83.95.E3.82.A9.E3.83.AB.E3.83.88_.E3.82.A2.E3.82.A4.E3.82.B3.E3.83.B3)を参照してください(XE8のものですが、XE5でも同様のはず)。